# ios Event Kit using my own notifications

Tags: ios, push-notification, eventkit

Using Apple's [EventKit.framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EventKitFrameworkRef/_index.html), the notifications can only come from Calendars app and Reminders app. Any way to make my own notifications but use Apple's calendar database? I mean that the notification would come from my own app... Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to register the event in the built-in Calendar database using EventKit, but use [iOS Local Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1) to actually schedule the notification so that it will originate from your app.

But beyond that, there is no way to set your app to open when a standard EventKit-stored event notification is shown.

Comment: I also thought about that, but if the user would create an event from his iCal on OS X, he wouldn't be able to set an alert.

Comment: Yeah, I don't believe there's a way to set your app (or any "alternate" app) to be opened when a standard EventKit event notification is shown. You basically just have to have your own calendar/event storage system to accomplish what you're talking about.